# Overwriting Variable in python issue

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python programming, please assist me.

I don't want to overwrite the **Admin** but it is forcing me to do that.

```
def funk(Admin="subhanshu",*users,**additional):
    print("Admin is", Admin)
    print("users are", users)
    print("additional are", additional)
```

When I run the function, it is throwing an error.

`funk(pass,'arun',"abcd",name='prakhar',age=23)`

## invalid syntex

Please help me how to call a function without over-riding the value of **Admin**  in the function.

Comment: what is pass you need to define it and accommodate it in funk function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of parameters in your function signature.

```
>>> def funk(*users, Admin='subhanshu', **additional):
...     print("Admin is", Admin)
...     print("users are", users)
...     print("additional are", additional)
...
>>> funk('these', 'are', 'all', 'users', this='is', additional=True)
Admin is subhanshu
users are ('these', 'are', 'all', 'users')
additional are {'this': 'is', 'additional': True}
```

The way that you have defined the function means that the first positional argument passed to the function will always be assigned to the `Admin` variable. By defining the function so that `Admin` comes after the positional arguments (`*users`) with a default value, it becomes an optional keyword argument.